# "Cannot find script file" error but file is actually there

Tags: php, build, php-extension, phpize

Disclaimer: am beginner.

I'm trying to build this certain PHP extension on Visual Studio Code 2017 in the Integrated Terminal, and I tried using the phpize command (there is an environment variable for the directory). It keeps outputting

```
C:\xampp\php\ext\php-geos
$ C:\xampp\php\php-src-php-7.2.6\win32\build\phpize
Input Error: Can not find script file "C:\xampp\php\php-src-php-7.2.6\win32\build\phpize.js".
Error generating configure script, configure script was not copied
```

even though it's right there. The file path is right. I checked the folder.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: the `.js` file was actually a `.js.in` file. I solved the problem by changing the extension, but I guess another solution is to edit `phpize` and put `.in` where it is applicable.